# Calculation mode of second instance of Excel application

Tags: vba, excel

I noticed when playing with a second instance of Excel that trying to access the calculation mode property causes a run-time error. Anyone seen this before? Stepping through the below code will replicate (I've commented the error line near the bottom)

```
Sub test1()

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .EnableEvents = True
End With

Debug.Print "This Application:"
Debug.Print vbTab & "ScreenUpdating: " & Application.ScreenUpdating
Debug.Print vbTab & "Calculation Mode: " & Application.Calculation
Debug.Print vbTab & "Events: " & Application.EnableEvents
Debug.Print "--------------------------------------------------------"

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

Debug.Print "This Application (After Change):"
Debug.Print vbTab & "ScreenUpdating: " & Application.ScreenUpdating
Debug.Print vbTab & "Calculation Mode: " & Application.Calculation
Debug.Print vbTab & "Events: " & Application.EnableEvents
Debug.Print "--------------------------------------------------------"

Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Set xlApp = New Excel.Application

Debug.Print "New Application:"
Debug.Print vbTab & "ScreenUpdating: " & xlApp.ScreenUpdating
Debug.Print vbTab & "Calculation Mode: " & xlApp.Calculation    '// Run-time error 13: Type mismatch
Debug.Print vbTab & "Events: " & xlApp.EnableEvents
Debug.Print "--------------------------------------------------------"

xlApp.Quit

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .EnableEvents = True
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You added/made a new instance of excel and it doesnt come with a workbook 'yet'. The new instance of excel do not have a workbook to work with yet. Be it visible or not it really throw an error. You can add a workbook like;

```
xlApp.Workbooks.Add
```

HTH.

Comment: Offtopic: Is it somewhat related to my question ealier?

Comment: Yes it is related, but also the `.Calculation` property is an application level property, not a workbook property. If it's dependent on a workbook then I want to know why

Comment: I can only assume, like when we try to `Property Get [Name of property]`,i guess the `.Calculation` property needs a valid reference?

Comment: Even still, the reference should be the application instance - I could perhaps understand `Property Let` if it needed to affect the workbooks collection or something, but for `Property Get` I can't see why it would depend on a workbooks collection.

Comment: unrelated - but as an FYI if you need it: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111528/vba-lounge

Comment: Apologies if my knowledge is not enough. But I am very delighted to have this conversation with you, its just too extensive for me. :)

Comment: No need to apologise! haha It's not an urgent question, just something that struck my curiousity